# Query to find duplicates in Access table

Tags: ms-access-2003

I have exhausted all examples I can find and I am still not getting the results I need.

I have an invoice table where I need to find any instance where the same invoice number is used on more than one customer. An invoice number can occur multiple times in the table and each record is distinguished by invoice and invoice seq no, but there should only be one customer per invoice, but some errors have crept in.

What I need is a report of only those invoice that have two or more customers. In the data below Cust 45001301 should not be the customer number for Invoice 708, seq 3.

```
Cust No Invoice No  Seq No  Input Date
700180  708 1   9/30/2007
700180  708 2   9/30/2007 
45001301    708 3   9/30/2007
700180  708 4   9/30/2007
700190  709 1   9/30/2007
700190  709 2   9/30/2007
```

What I have tried to do is just get a simple group by query to show me only those invoices with more than one customer much like this-

```
[Invoice No] [Cust no]
   708          700180 
   708        45001301
```

But I ONLY want to see those with two or more customers, so in the above example I would not see the entry for invoice 709 because it only has the one customer.

```
[Invoice No] [Cust no]
   708          700180 
   708        45001301
   709          700190
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add the query you're using to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a query which returns all distinct combinations of `[Invoice No]` and `[Cust no]`.  Then use that as a subquery where you count the number of customers per `[Invoice No]` and add a `HAVING` clause to limit the output to only those where the count is greater than one.

```sql
SELECT sub.[Invoice No], Count(*) AS customers
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [Invoice No], [Cust no]
        FROM Invoices
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.[Invoice No]
HAVING Count(*) > 1;
```

If you then need to see *which* customers where duplicated for those invoices, `INNER JOIN` that query back to the `Invoices` table.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT i.[Invoice No], sub2.customers, i.[Cust No]
FROM
    Invoices AS i
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT sub.[Invoice No], Count(*) AS customers
        FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT [Invoice No], [Cust no]
                FROM Invoices
            ) AS sub
        GROUP BY sub.[Invoice No]
        HAVING Count(*) > 1
    ) AS sub2
    ON i.[Invoice No] = sub2.[Invoice No];
```

With Access 2007 and your sample data in a table named `Invoices`, that query gives me this result set:

```sql
Invoice No customers Cust No
708                2   700180
708                2 45001301
```

If you actually wanted to see *all* the data for those duplicate invoice numbers, change the first line of the second query to this:

```sql
SELECT i.[Invoice No], sub2.customers, i.[Cust No], i.[Seq No], i.[Input Date]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Now maybe all the hair I yanked out over this will start to grow back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT inv.[cust no],
       inv.[invoice no],
       inv.[seq no],
       inv.[input date]
FROM   inv
       INNER JOIN (SELECT q.[invoice no],
                          Count(q.[invoice no]) AS [CountOfInvoice No]
                   FROM   (SELECT inv.[invoice no],
                                  inv.[cust no]
                           FROM   inv
                           GROUP  BY inv.[invoice no],
                                     inv.[cust no]) AS q
                   GROUP  BY q.[invoice no]
                   HAVING (( ( Count(q.[invoice no]) ) > 1 ))) AS q2
ON inv.[invoice no] = q2.[invoice no]
```

Where inv is the name of your table.

The query returns all details and rows for invoice numbers that have more than one associated customer number.

```
cust no invoice no  seq no  input date
700180      708     4       30/09/2007
45001301    708     3       30/09/2007
700180      708     2       30/09/2007
700180      708     1       30/09/2007
```

Comment: If the idea is to correct a problem, it is generally useful to get all available data. The question may be stated more simply than the actual requirement.